# Better Method to Replace If/Else Chain

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to simplify my controller that is being used within my SQL command to filter records based on specific criteria. My attempt below works, but has many flaws. The most obvious is that it isn't scalable as I may add in more critera as time goes on and the second is that I am unable to leave specific fields undefined and run the query. I would prefer if a value is left undefined that they are not added in the query. All of the parameters are appended as query parameters and then capture and processed.

**Nested If/Else used in query:**

```
var whereFilterObject = {};
if (req.query.blogDateStart && req.query.blogDateEnd && req.query.blogType) {
    whereFilterObject = {
        blogDate: {
            $between: [req.query.blogDateStart, req.query.blogDateEnd]
        },
        type: req.query.blogType
    }
} else if (req.query.blogDateStart && req.query.blogDateEnd) {
    whereFilterObject = {
        blogDate: {
            $between: [req.query.blogDateStart, req.query.blogDateEnd]
        }
    }
} else if (req.query.blogType) {
    whereFilterObject = {
        type: req.query.blogType
    }
} else {
    limitAmount = {
        limit: 10
    }
}
```

Appended query parameters on Post method:

```
if (blogDateStart && blogDateEnd && blogDateEnd) {
    res.redirect('/app?' + 'blogDateStart=' + blogDateStart + '&' + 'blogDateEnd=' + blogDateEnd + '&' + 'blogType=' + blogType);
} else if (blogDateStart && blogDateEnd) {
    res.redirect('/app?' + 'blogDateStart=' + blogDateStart + '&' + 'blogDateEnd=' + blogDateEnd);
} else {
    res.redirect('/app?' + 'blogType=' + blogType);
}
```

Comment: you could use a function with early return to prevent else parts.

Comment: You should create different routes per scenario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you don't need to do a chain like that. You can check for each query parameter individually (based on your needs) and just set the object key as needed.

```
var whereFilterObject = {};

var hasDateConditions = (req.query.blogDateStart && req.query.blogDateEnd);
var hasType = req.query.hasOwnProperty('blogType');

if (hasDateConditions) {
    whereFilterObject['blogDate'] = {
        $between: [req.query.blogDateStart, req.query.blogDateEnd]
    }
}

if (hasType) {
    whereFilterObject['type'] = req.query.blogType;
}

if (!hasType && !hasDateConditions) {
    limitAmount = {
        limit: 10
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that `if (req.query.hasOwnProperty('blogType'))` is not the same as `if (req.query.blogType)` if `blogType` exists and has a falsey value so this doesn't quite generate the same results as the OP's code.  General direction looks good though.

Comment: @jfriend00 sorry can you explain that a bit more?

Comment: @cphill - Your code did an `if (req.query.blogType)`.  That checks to see if the property exists and has a truthy value.  This answer does an `if (req.query.hasOwnProperty('blogType'))` which only checks to see if the property exists and will pass the `if` test even if the property has a falsey value such as `undefined`, `false`, `0`, etc...  So, this code does not do quite the same thing as your code if that difference matters.